# Masking a redirection in IIS7

Tags: redirects, iis7, masking

My tools:

- IIS7
- 1 x Windows 2008 Server
- IIS URL Rewrite Module 2 (installed)

My requirement:

- Mask the redirection of `www.bob.com` to `www.abc.com/bob/index.html` - the end user should not see the `www.abc.com`
- The user should then be able to browse the website as normal.

I have found references to installing AAR, however this seems to be more for load balancing etc.?  Then others have said use a 3rd party tool etc.

Answer (score 1):

For IIS7 you will indeed need AAR. There are 3rd party modules available that can do what you need as well such as Helicon Ape:
https://www.helicontech.com/ape/

Using AAR:
[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosag/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr)

You'll be reverse proxying requests for http://www.bob.com/ to http://www.example.com/bob/

In Apache, with the correct modules loaded, it can be done as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bob\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/bob$1 [P,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following article [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/01/26/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site.aspx).  It appears to describe a very similar situation as to what you are trying to setup.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer in places so that nobody has to click through to at least get the main idea?